# VB.NET how do I insulate a class from accessing external functions

Tags: vb.net, oop, class, module

We are working on updating a code project that has become very messy over time. There are lots of modules which contain public functions that can be used from anywhere.

We want to move as much of the code into classes as possible, so that these can eventually be re-used in the next generation of the application. Is there a way that we can prevent these classes from using any (non-system) functions?

Example:

```
public module annoyingModule
 public function addOneAndOne() as int
     return 2
 end function
 .....(load more functions)....
end module

public class pricer
 ...(class code)...
end class
```

I want to make sure that nobody on the team can accidentally make a reference to the addOneAndOne function - if they need functionality from a module which is not part of the class, they need to re-implement it inside the new class.

Comment: What do you mean "re-implement it inside the class function"? Also, what are you considering a (non-system) function?

Comment: I mean instead of making use of the addOneAndOne() function which is provided by the annoyingModule, they need to re-implement the code inside the pricer class. I want to make a class that can be taken out of this project and used in another straight away, so I don't want it to have access to any of the modules that are already in the project.

Comment: Why not just make them private or delete them from the code altogether? Am I missing something that makes this not obvious?

Comment: If I make them private or delete them the entire rest of the application will stop functioning...

Comment: So you want to be able to call them without being able to call them? Do you see the problem here? Just move them to a class and fix your existing code. The compiler will find all of the calls for you and make it easy to fix. I think you are making this a lot more complicated than you need to.

Comment: Are you deliberately being difficult? I want to be able to call them from the rest of the code, but NOT from the new classes we are writing. I want to know if there is any way of insulating a class from the rest of the code, so it can't make use of public modules that have previously been written?

Comment: Your request is nonsensical. That's why it may appear I am being difficult. The compiler has no idea what code was "previously written" so no. What you are asking is impossible. The good news is that even if it was possible it would be a bad idea. Just move the code to a new class and fix the existing references.

Comment: I am working with a team of people. I want to make sure that other people are not accidentally leaving references to functions that will no longer be available in the future. I would have thought there may be a modifier for a class that would only allow access to functions available as part of the .NET framework and not allow access to other public modules within the codebase. If there isn't then there isn't, but it's hardly a nonsensical request, it must be a problem than most developers involved in maintaining messy codebases have had to deal with over the years.

Comment: There is. That what private is for (or better yet, deleting them). You are asking for the compiler to read your mind and know that some calls (the existing code) can make the call and new code (whatever that means) can't. You just don't seem to want to do the obvious answer and delete or make private the code you don't want called.

Comment: If you have nothing more useful to say then please please don't comment any more. You're just irritating me now. I want to say 'THIS CLASS CAN MAKE USE OF THE .NET FRAMEWORK BUT NO OTHER MODULES INSIDE THIS PROJECT' While still allowing the other 300 modules/classes to interact with each other. Deleting or making the modules private means the entire codebase is broken and needs fixing up which by itself could take years

Comment: The only way to do that is to move the class OUT of the project and/or namespace that you have the public methods. The answer to your question is No, there is no feature that says "This method is public except when I don't think it should be."

Comment: Nice pedal back, but I never asked for a way to make the methods public except in certain cases. I asked for a way to prevent new classes accessing existing methods. Thankfully somebody has taken the effort to understand and answer the question productively.

Comment: If only you had taken the time to ASK the question productively. Of course it is possible. I just told you the exact same answer, you just refuse to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your new classes to a separate class library project.  As long as your new class library project does not reference the old project and does not include a copy of the old modules, all of that stuff will be inaccessible from the classes in that class library project.  You then, in the old project, need to add a reference to your new class library project.  That way, the old code can use the new classes, but the new classes will not be able to use the old modules.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I've been in this same situation myself.  Saying that you can just rewrite or delete the legacy code is not always realistic and the best you can do is take baby steps towards fixing it and at least stop the spread of the madness into new code.